# Why function exist in .o file, but does not exist in .so file?

Tags: c, gcc, asterisk

Why function MyFunc() exist in .o file, but does not exist in .so file?
Example .o file:

```
00019350 g     F .text  00000034 MyFunc
```

In .so file I don't see function "MyFunc".

Comment: readelf -a ./myfile.so

Comment: How did you produce `00019350 g     F .text  00000034 MyFunc`? What tool?

Comment: This is part of makefile.rules: 
%: %.o
 $(ECHO_PREFIX) echo "   [LD] $^ -> $@"
 $(CMD_PREFIX) $(CXX) $(STATIC_BUILD) -o $@ $(PTHREAD_CFLAGS) $(_ASTLDFLAGS) $^ $(CXX_LIBS) $(ASTLDFLAGS)

Comment: Is MyFunc exported?

Comment: 2Peter L.: Surely.

Comment: Can you show the code you used to export it?

Comment: 2Ian Abbott: Not right now.

Comment: If the function is not called, it may be removed from the .so by link time optimization (LTO), if you have that - just an option

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The my trouble happens because I made mistake for depend of method of declaration function.

I forgot to clarify that I'm transferring the old code from asterisk 1.4. to asterisk 13.21. (http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk/)
ATTENTION: The way to define the exported functions in the this project is own of asterisk company (since 13 version).
So, in order for the exported functions to be available in the ".so" file, these functions MUST BE explicitly specified in the text file (with prefix "LINKER_SYMBOL_PREFIX"), which have same name as the source file, but with the extension ".exports.in", e.g.:

```
myfile.h (contains: int MyFunc();)
myfile.c (contains: int MyFunc(){})
myfile.exports.in (contains: LINKER_SYMBOL_PREFIXMyFunc)
```

After compile, all needed functions will be availble in "myfile.so".
That is design.

Many thanks to all guys.